# How to put text inside Donut Chart in Nativescript-Vue?

Tags: charts, nativescript, nativescript-vue

Could someone please help me to put a text inside a Donut Chart in NativeScript? I use Nativescript-Vue with standard plugin **nativescript-ui-chart**. In the [documentation](https://docs.nativescript.org/vuejs/ns-ui/chart/series/overview#chartseries-presenting-numerical-proportion) there is an example of a Donut Chart with a text inside, like a calculated value from the series. I cannot find a way to build the same of any live example of it.

[Example: Text inside Donut Chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vG2Hl.png)

Here is my code of Donut Chart:

```html
<RadPieChart allowAnimation="true" row="1" column="0" height="200">
    <DonutSeries v-tkPieSeries
    seriesName="chartExample"
    selectionMode="DataPoint"
    expandRadius="0.4"
    outerRadiusFactor="1"
    innerRadiusFactor="0.6"
    valueProperty="value"
    legendLabel="name"
    showLabels="false"
    :items="chartItems" />
</RadPieChart>

<script>
export default {
    props: {
        chartData: {
            type: Object,
            required: false,
            default: undefined
        },
    },
    computed: {
        chartItems() {
            return [ { name: 'front', value: this.chartData.front }, { name: 'front left', value: 100 - this.chartData.front } ]
        }
}
</script>
```

Comment: maby via css like https://github.com/ProgressNS/nativescript-ui-samples-vue/blob/master/chart/app/examples/css/DonutCss.ts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a `GridLayout` to stack things on the z index, and put your text either to the front or behind the pie chart.

`GridLayout` stacks its contents by the order it is defined - the one towards the bottom of the layout will be stacked higher. For example, in the code below, since `Label` is defined after `RadPieChart`, it will be positioned above the chart.

```html
<GridLayout rows="auto" columns="auto">
  <RadPieChart allowAnimation="true" row="1" column="0" height="200">
    <DonutSeries v-tkPieSeries
    seriesName="chartExample"
    selectionMode="DataPoint"
    expandRadius="0.4"
    outerRadiusFactor="1"
    innerRadiusFactor="0.6"
    valueProperty="value"
    legendLabel="name"
    showLabels="false"
    :items="chartItems" />
  </RadPieChart>

  <!-- whatever text you want to put inside the chart -->
  <Label text="Your text here"></Label>
</GridLayout>
```